# Overlay jQuery Lightbox with Bookmarklet

Tags: jquery, lightbox, bookmarklet

Looking to create a bookmarklet that let's users store useful information. Is it possible to create a bookmarklet that loads a jQuery lightbox on click? I can get it working on my own domain, but the lightbox doesn't load when on a different domain I do not control.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question does not contain enough details to answer. Provide same code.

Comment: Please provide more details ... I understand it like you have been able to create a bookmarklet which works for your domain/site but not on others ... generally, one of these 2 must be happening: either your code is not able to handle DOM structure of the other site ... or the other site that you are testing with restricts JavaScript from other domains (eg: Your bookmarklets would not load on Facebook, Gmail which block loading external JavaScript files)